# How to define an schema for email so it will accept number as well as special characters and string also using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to define an schema for email so it will accept number as well as special characters and string also using mongoose,

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed`
  }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be String ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String, }, email: { type: String } });
```

type: String can store any type of character